# select change not firing with optgroups

Tags: jquery

I have a  tag that has optgroups:

```
            <div id="quick-zoom">
                Quick Zoom: 
                <select id="quick_zoom_select" name="quick_zoom_select">
                    <option value="0">Default</option>
                    <optgroup label="Computers" id="computers">
                    <option value=.95>iMac G3</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Mobiles" id="mobiles">
                    <option value=1.5>Nexus 7(portrait)</option>
                    <option value=1.5>Nexus 7(landscape)</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="Clear"></div>
```

And jQuery statement to detect a change in the select:

```
$('#quick_zoom').change(function(){
        Zoom($(this).val());
});
```

The .change is not firing. When I remove the optgroup tags it does fire. Can someone tell me what is going on?

Thank you,
Todd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#quick_zoom_select').change(function(){
        Zoom($(this).val());
});
```

You've tried to apply the change to a div when it should be on the select.

Here is a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ZSquF/

Comment: Feel free to click the checkmark next to the answer if it helped you.  This is how future visitors can be helped and is also how Stack Overflow works.